# Redirecting to Vimeo player

Tags: android, video, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

How to launch vimeo intent from android application.
I tired using the following link....

**http://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID**

But it is getting crashed from Vimeo application with the following error :

```
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144): **uncaught exception**
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144): **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vimeo.android.lib.ui.player.LaunchFullScreenVideoPlayerFullScreenVideoPlayer**
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-28 17:46:12.076: E/Vimeo(4144):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please suggest me...
Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Please add the relevant code

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://player.vimeo.com/video/40886162")));

Answer (score 1):

This question is super old, adding a new answer based on the recently updated Vimeo Android App (relaunched in December 2015). You can now deeplink into the official Vimeo Android app. You can do this manually or by using the [vimeo-deeplink](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-deeplink-android) library. Even if you don't use the library, check out its README file for a description of the Vimeo app's deeplink API.

You might also be interested in the [Vimeo Android SDK](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java).

Note: I work at Vimeo

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** it will navigate to Vimeo app.

```
try{
   Intent browserIntent = null;
   PackageManager pmi = getPackageManager();
   browserIntent =     pmi.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.vimeo.android.videoapp");
   browserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
// browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://player.vimeo.com/video/83178705"));

   startActivity(browserIntent);
}
catch(Exception e){
   // App is not Installed
   //Navigate to Play Store or display message
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "In Catch Block", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```